# Swift/Xcode dependency management approach

Tags: xcode, swift, dependency-management

I'm looking at configuring SwiftyJSON.  The [docs](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#integration) state you can configure the library using any of these methods:

1. CocoaPods
2. Carthage
3. Swift Package Manager
4. Manual

What are the pros and cons of these approaches when configuring external libraries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some points about each of them

**1. CocoaPods**

Pros

- Most widely used dependency manager.
- Almost every popular libraries, framework vendors provide pod for their library/framework.
- You can try the library and its usage without manually downloading it manually. `pod try` command

Cons

- You should manage your project with a workspace.
- If any vendor is not adding or updating their library's pod spec, it will be difficult to maintain.

**2. Carthage**

Pros

- No need to keep the project in a workspace.
- It's not a centralized system, that is no need to wait for the vendor to update/add the library to any centralized repo.

Cons

- Need to add your frameworks to project for the first time.

**3. Swift Package Manager**

Pros

- Product from creators/maintainers of swift itself.
- No extra workspace created.
- Super easy to integrate.
  Cons
- <s>Not very popular.</s>
- <s>Still, need to be adopted by the developer community.</s>

**4. Manual**

Pros

- You have full control.
- You can edit(if the license allows to..).

Cons

- Need manual work to add dependencies.
- Difficult to update libraries.
- Not sure whether we can add Objective-C libs to project using Swift Package Manager.

I would suggest using `CocoaPods` because its very simple to use and will get enough help and resources from the internet.

In WWDC 2019, Apple introduced Xcode 11 with the built-in feature to use SPM. So it would be easy to use SPM as Cocoapods.